# MS word find and replace: Change how to replace based on captured values in Find's RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am working on bilingual documents (Arabic-English), The two languages have different directions (RTL and LTR respectively) which makes working with it a bit more challenging.

I am writing a macro to change numbers of the form (x.x) to (x,x), a change in the comma.

now here is the problem, sometimes the two numbers are switched when I do the replace, for example: x.y becomes y,x.

after some debugging it turned out that sometimes this (.) in the first form is an Arabic character and when it is replaced with (,) which is an English one it is causing this change in order.

so I want to do is the following, but I don't know how to translate it to VBA:

```
1- look for a match to the expression ([0-9]{1, }).([0-9]{1, }) 'two numbers with a dot in between

2- if the dot in between is English, replace as follows \1,\2  'no change  
3- else if it is Arabic, replace as follows \2,\1
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**
here is the current version of the macro, it is a recorded macro. I just added the if else statement.

```
Sub fixComma()
'
' fixComma Macro
'
'
   If (Selection.Start <> Selection.End) Then
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([0-9]).([0-9])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1,\2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Else
      MsgBox "Nothing is selected, Macro terminated"
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**
Maybe I am taking the wrong approach here and I should go through the paragraphs myself and check for a match for the RegEx instead of using Find and Replace ?

**EDIT 3**
Maybe I am using the wrong tool here and VBA can't help me with this ? if so is there anything else I can use ? maybe a C# add in for example.

Comment: What is the code point for the Arabic character? Please check with [this converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Comment: `002E` which is the same as the English one apparently

Comment: If it's the same code point, I wonder what would cause it to use RTL.

Comment: Maybe it is an attribute msword attach to each character, not just through code points. I don't know how MS WORD deals with that

Comment: Could be. Unfortunately, it sounds like the key to your fix will be distinguishing `.` (English) from `.` (Arabic).

Comment: yeah, it boils down to that, there is this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171960(v=office.11).aspx  , but not sure how can I use it with the RegEx

Comment: There is a pair of methods on `Selection`: [`LtrRun`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839502.aspx) and [`RtlRun`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821034.aspx) which set the text direction of the run. If both Arabic `.` and English `.` are the same code point, then this might help.

Comment: These methods refer to a mysterious **ReadingOrder** property, which is probably a better choice; but I can't find it in the MSDN reference.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to find and replace.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, here you go but I started to think it is the wrong approach to begin with